# How to hook into fivestar_ajax_submit function?

Tags: ajax, forms, rating

I have to add custom HTML element for rate stars and I tried to this with alter fivestar_custom_widget form and set:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#ajax']['callback'] = 'MODULE_fivestar_ajax_submit';
```

I created MODULE_fivestar_ajax_submit function where I call original fivestar_ajax_submit.
My problem is that I can't instruct $form to use my function in place of original code.

-- edit --

In MYMODULE_form_alter() I'v got:

```
if ($form_id == 'fivestar_custom_widget') {
    $arg0 = arg(0);
    $arg1 = arg(1);
    if ($arg0 == 'node' && !empty($arg1) && ctype_digit($arg1)) {
        $node = node_load($arg1);
        $form['votes_counter'] = array(
            '#markup' => '<div class="votes-countes">' . format_plural($node->field_rating[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['count'], '1 vote', '@count votes') . '</div>'
        );
        $form['#submit'] = array(
            'MYMODULE_fivestar_form_submit'
        );

        $form['actions']['submit']['#ajax']['callback'] = 'MYMODULE_fivestar_ajax_submit';
        $form['#submit'] = array('MYMODULE_fivestar_ajax_submit');
    }
}
```

and submit function:

```
function MYMODULE_fivestar_ajax_submit($form, $form_state) {
    $result = fivestar_ajax_submit($form, $form_state);
    $result['#commands']['data'] .= format_plural(100, '1 vote', '@count votes');
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: You need a form_alter to change the submit function, form submit callbacks are not treated as hooks.

Comment: I also tried with MODULE_form_alter() and fivestar_custom_widget as $form_id, but in this table can't find any informations about original call to fivestar_ajax_submit(). Thus I don't know where to put/override information about my custom _submit().

Comment: You need to set the '#submit' property. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend helped me with this solution:

```
function MYMODULE_element_info_alter(&$info) {
    $info['fivestar']['#process'][] = 'MYMODULE_fivestar_process';
}

function MYMODULE_fivestar_process($element) {
    $element['vote']['#ajax']['callback'] = 'MYMODULE_fivestar_ajax_submit';
    return $element;
}

function MYMODULE_fivestar_ajax_submit($form, $form_state) {
    $result = fivestar_ajax_submit($form, $form_state);

    $type = $form_state['build_info']['args'][1]['content_type'];
    $id = $form_state['build_info']['args'][1]['content_id'];
    $votes = fivestar_get_votes($type, $id, 'vote', $GLOBALS['user']->uid);

    $result['#commands'][] = array(
        'command' => 'insert',
        'method' => 'replaceWith',
        'selector' => 'span.vote-count',
        'data' => '<span class="vote-count">' . format_plural($votes['count']['value'], '1 vote', '@count votes') . '</span>',
        'effect' => 'fade'
    );
    return $result;
}
```

This code adds and change votes counter displayed after fivestar voting widget.